# Macro to select specific columns from multiple csv and importing to one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have multiple CSV in one directory, I need to select specific files instead of the entire directory and I want to be able to select the column that I want (X) and import this to a single worksheet!

I have already made the code above but I'm fighting to add a input box that give the capability do select the column that I want to extract from each CSV.
Moreover, whenever I import the CSV there are not sorted correctly. I found out that I need to apply this formula `""=LEFT(F1;1)&TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(F1;LEFT(F1;1);"";"00") " "`, but any idea how to apply in code in order to rename the .csv files.

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReferenceI()

Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As String
Dim xCount As Long
Dim Newname As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Add

Newname = InputBox("Name for new worksheet?")
If Newname <> "" Then
    Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = Newname
 End If
Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet


If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo, "Kutools for Excel") = vbYes Then
    xSht.UsedRange.Clear
    xCount = 1
Else
    xCount = xSht.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")

Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)

    Rows(1).Insert xlShiftDown
    Range("A1") = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Cells(1, xCount)
    xWb.Close False
    xFile = Dir
    xCount = xSht.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "error"
End Sub
```

Data example (some times I want to extract the columns A or B or C or .... :

[image]

Example of a result:
[image]